# Exponential sums with monomials with divisor-function coefficients

Tags: nt.number-theory, reference-request, analytic-number-theory, exponential-sums

In their paper "Exponential Sums with Monomials," Fouvry and Iwaniec study exponential sums roughly of the form
$$
\sum_{m_1 \sim M_1} \cdots \sum_{m_r \sim M_r} c_1(m_1) \cdots c_r(m_r) e\left(x \frac{m_1^{\alpha_1}}{M_1^{\alpha_1}}\cdots \frac{m_r^{\alpha_r}}{M_r^{\alpha_r}} \right),
$$
where the coefficients satisfy $|c_i(m_i)| \leq 1$, $r\in\{2,3,4\}$,$x > 0$, and $\alpha_1,\ldots,\alpha_r \neq 0$. They estimate these sums in terms of $M_1,\ldots, M_r$ and $x$. I'm wondering if anyone has considered these sums with the additional hypothesis that $c_i(m_i) = \tau(m_i)$ for one or more of the coefficients $c_i$. Here $\tau(m)$ denotes the number of divisors of $m$.  Of course, this is technically already covered by Fouvry and Iwaniec's work (take two of the $\alpha_i$ equal), but their proofs do not take advantage of the underlying $GL_2$ structure provided by the specific coefficients $\tau(m_r)$. I have in mind some of Jutila's work, especially his "Lectures on a Method in the Theory of Exponential Sums," where he studies such exponential sums in a single variable with divisor-function coefficients using a $GL_2$ summation formula. For the applications I have in mind, I would like an average form of Jutila's estimates. For instance, I would like to estimate
$$
\sum_{m_1 \sim M_1} \sum_{m_2 \sim M_2} c_1(m_1) \tau(m_2) e\left(x \frac{m_1^{\alpha_1} m_2^{\alpha_2}}{M_1^{\alpha_1}M_2^{\alpha_2}} \right)
$$
without just using Jutila's work directly to estimate
$$
\sum_{m_1 \sim M_1} \bigg| \sum_{m_2 \sim M_2} \tau(m_2) e\left(x \frac{m_1^{\alpha_1} m_2^{\alpha_2}}{M_1^{\alpha_1}M_2^{\alpha_2}} \right) \bigg|.
$$

If no one has considered these types of exponential sums (specifically, with monomials in the phase of the exponential) from the perspective I've described, I think it would make for an interesting project. However, these sums seem common enough that I would be somewhat surprised if they hadn't been studied in this way. As such, before I spend time on this, I figured I'd ask and see if anyone knows of research in this direction. Any references are most appreciated.